# Jquery: Select a radio button when table row is selected

Tags: jquery

I need to have a radio button selected when a user clicks anywhere in a table row. I have been toying with some options but cannot get anything to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is a sample table:

```
<table id="tableSelect" class="rowclick" border=1>
<caption align="top">User Management</caption> <thead>
<tr id='head'>
    <th scope="Row">Select</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Greeting Name</th>
    <th>Dept</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Access Level</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id='one'>
        <th scope="col">
            <input name="UserSelected" id="userSelected_1" type="radio" value="1">
        </th>
        <th scope="col"> Richard Rice</th>
        <td>Rick</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>rick</td>
        <td>
            <select class="Role" id="Role" name="userAccessLevel">
                <option value="-2">Access Denied</option>
                <option value="-1">Suspended</option>
                <option value="1">Shipping User</option>
                <option value="2">Administrator</option>
                <option value="3" selected>Super Administrator</option>
                <option value="5">Accounting</option>
                <option value="6">Report Viewer</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='two'>
        <th scope="col">                          
            <input name="UserSelected" id="userSelected_2" type="radio" value="3">
        </th>
        <th scope="col"> Mickey Hockenberry</th>                     
        <td>Mickey</td>
        <td>Purchasing</td>
        <td>mickeyh</td>
        <td>
            <select class="Role"  id="Role" name="userAccessLevel">
                <option value="-2">Access Denied</option>
                <option value="-1">Suspended</option>
                <option value="1">Shipping User</option>
                <option value="2" selected>Administrator</option>
                <option value="3">Super Administrator</option>
                <option value="5">Accounting</option>
                <option value="6">Report Viewer</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='three'>
        <th scope="col">                          
            <input name="UserSelected" id="userSelected_3" type="radio" value="41">                    
        </th>
        <th scope="col"> Michael Lynch</th>
        <td>Mike</td>
        <td>Shipping</td>
        <td>mjl</td>
        <td>
            <select class="Role"  id="Role" name="userAccessLevel">
                <option value="-2">Access Denied</option>
                <option value="-1">Suspended</option>
                <option value="1">Shipping User</option>
                <option value="2" selected>Administrator</option>
                <option value="3">Super Administrator</option>
                <option value="5">Accounting</option>
                <option value="6">Report Viewer</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#tableSelect tr').click(function() {
    $(this).find('th input:radio').prop('checked', true);
})
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/eFnL7/1/

**Edit:** For better (by how much??) performance, use `input[type=radio]` selector : http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/eFnL7/2/

Comment: Both of these works nicely. I appreciate the help. I totally forgot about the find function in jquery. Thanks.

Comment: Change `find('th input:radio')` to `find('input[type=radio]')`. No need to check for `th`, and `type=radio` is faster than `:radio` in most cases. See comments to my answer.

Comment: @Joseph Silber: Already did! I would keep the `th` as I like to be as specific as possible.

Comment: You do realize that that also has a performance hit (altough, like you say, bu how much?).

Comment: If you're talking about having `th`, accuracy here takes a precedence. Tomorrow I can add another `radio` to anywhere in my table without worrying about breaking (or need to change) existing code. Ideal would be to use `th input[name="UserSelected"]` or just `input[name="UserSelected"]` which gives best of performance and accuracy.

Comment: You saved my day !!..Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#tableSelect tr').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8PzX2/

Documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('table tr').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Why? Look at this: "Because :radio is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :radio cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="radio"] instead." http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/

Comment: For most purposes, especially a single selector call, the difference in performance will be completely inconsequential - I prefer the pseudoclass selector for its terseness and better readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#tableSelect').delegate('tbody > tr', 'click', function ()
    {
        $(this).find('input[name="UserSelected"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delegate` to do this which will attach the event handler only to the table element and will work for each `tr`

```
    $(function (){
        $('#tableSelect').delegate('tbody > tr', 'click', function(){
            $(this).find('input[name="UserSelected"]').attr('checked', true);
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Matt - That might be a coincidence, I always prefer to use delegate for such you can check my other answers