# how to get selected(radio button) row value(label) in gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here is a code i am trying to do but it is not working properly

```
$("#a_btn").click(function () 
{
    if(('table[id*="GridView_Customer"] input[type="radio"]:checked')) 
        {
           var lblStatus = $('table[id*="GridView_Customer"] [id*="lblStatus"]').text();
           alert(lblStatus);
        }
 }
```

when i select "RadioButton_Select" and click on a_btn need to get "lblStatus" value

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1** Including html:

```
    <a id="a_btn">cancel</a> 
     //Anchor tag 
 <asp:gridview id="GridView_Customer" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" > 
       <Columns> 
            <asp:TemplateField> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                   <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="RadioButton_Select" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:RadioButton>
                 </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 
           <asp:TemplateField > 
               <ItemTemplate> 
                   <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' width="80px" runat="server"> </asp:Label>                  
               </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 
       </Coloumns> 
</asp:Gridview>
```

Comment: try to use $(this).Parent get row element then you can search child nodes from that row

Comment: Can you provide the HTML structure?

Comment: <a id="a_btn">cancel</a> //Anchor tag

<asp:gridview id="GridView_Customer" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>                                       
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="RadioButton_Select"  
 AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:RadioButton>

</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField >  
    
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' width="80px" runat="server">

</asp:Label>

</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField> 

</Coloumns>

</asp:Gridview>

Comment: when i select "RadioButton_Select" and click on "a_btn" need to get "lblStatus" value

Comment: can you add the HTML that generated by your code?

Comment: <a id="a_btn">cancel</a> //Anchor tag <asp:gridview id="GridView_Customer" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" > <Columns> <asp:TemplateField> <ItemTemplate> <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="RadioButton_Select" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:RadioButton> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField > <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' width="80px" runat="server"> </asp:Label> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> </Coloumns> </asp:Gridview>

Comment: <a id="a_btn">cancel</a> //Anchor tag <asp:gridview id="GridView_Customer" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" > <Columns> <asp:TemplateField> <ItemTemplate> <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="RadioButton_Select" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:RadioButton> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField > <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' width="80px" runat="server"> </asp:Label> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> </Coloumns> </asp:Gridview> when i select "RadioButton_Select" and click on "a_btn" need to get "lblStatus" value

Comment: You should add the HTML structure that generated. Not source code asp.net web form. 
I hope anybody can help you.

Comment: this question is to click a radio button but hopefully the select part of the jquery will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067136/jquery-select-a-radio-button-when-table-row-is-selected

Answer (score 1):

```
        <asp:gridview id="GridView_Customer" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server"  OnRowCommand="gdBankDetils_RowCommand" > 
           <Columns> 
                <asp:TemplateField> 
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                       <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="RadioButton_Select" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:RadioButton>
                       <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' runat="server"/>
                     </ItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField> 
               <asp:TemplateField > 
                   <ItemTemplate> 
                       <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' width="80px" runat="server"> </asp:Label>                  
                   </ItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField> 
           </Coloumns> 
    </asp:Gridview>
```

Code bihind

```
protected void GridView_Customer_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
         //Perform Action
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an hidden field outside your grid and once you click on radio button, just set the hidden field value in gridview onrowcommand event with given command name.
when click on anchor button, you just get the value from hidden field..

May be it solves your problem.

thanks....